# IOS 9 view are being cut in the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c

Views are being cut in the bottom even if there is constraint for like 22 but as you can see in the picture below it's just like 2 or 3. The constraint is perfectly fine in ios 7 and ios 8(not really sure in ios 8) and this only happens in ios 9. I log the height of self.view(frame and bounds) and for iphone 5 I got 568 for both frame and bounds. How is this happening? And how can I fix this?

[image]

Here is the screen capture for ios8

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the constants aren't breaking? (Ex: You've set top/bottom AND fixed height constant). We would need to see your constants to give more accurate solutions

Comment: I set the relation of the white view to greater than or equal. I think it's the one who's messing but the height of the white view is only 477 and I'm using size classes and the height of the base is in default(600) the height of so it should stretch.

Comment: Uncheck the constraint to margin.

Comment: Show me all vertical constraints: White view top - superview, White view height, white view bottom - superview with all their properties: constant, relation (equal, less/greater than) and constraint to margin.

Comment: It's already unchecked when I create it.

Comment: Is this kind of bug in ios9 or just in my constraints?

Answer (score 1):

When drag any control on  any controller on storyboard it will be `alloc` and `init` and you can get its actual frame using `initWithCoder` that will be called  before you `init` on `viewDidLoad` method there to find the actual frame of your control you can manage it using this method.
Here is the method where you can adjust your control's frame :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self setActualFramewithinInitialization];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setActualFramewithinInitialization {

    //you can adjust the frame of your control with initializations   as you need    
}
```

This method is useful when you set your control's frame using `storyboard` or `nib` and you didn't get it right at the end.

**You have to initialize  you Control here because this method will call before initialization of your `View`**.